# Rails Gateway endpoints loaded from yml/env file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, gateway

I have been trying to implement the Rails API Gateway concept and I have been struggling with a way to define routes without too much of a hustle.
My current implementation looks something like this:

```
module ServicesEndpoints
  class StackOverflow
    def self.check_comment(id)
      begin
        RestClient.get endpoint + comment_path(id)
      rescue => e
        #if the server is not up or errors occur from our point of view there is no data about the driver
        raise my_error
      end
    end


    private

    def self.endpoint
      ENV['STACKOVERFLOW_SERVICE_ADDRESS']
    end

    def self.comment_path(id)
      "/comments/#{id}"
    end
  end
end
```

However this means that everytime i have to add an endpoint i need 1 class and for every route 1 action. Thinking about this I was wondering if you couldn't do this in an yml/.env file and just load them. However even if I know how to put the endpoint in the .env file routes with params are a little tricky(I have no good idea on how to do it).

Has someone tackled this problem and if so how did you go about to solve it?